# Connecting to Oracle 11g DB from Visual Studio 12

Tags: database, oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to my school's database for my final so that I can build a GUI for it. But I can't figure out how to get it to connect. The database is an Oracle 11g database that I'm trying to connect to. I've downloaded the Oracle Net Manager like my teacher has instructed and set it up properly and can connect to the server that way. But when I try to get VS to work, it can't connect. I downloaded dbForge Fusion for Oracle and am using that to try and connect in VS. When I set up the IP, and login info it gives me this error:

```
ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

Does that mean anything that is helpful to anyone?

Here is what is in my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Kristopher\product\11.2.0\client_2\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_DELPHIDB = TRUE

SID_LIST_DELPHIDB =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = delphidb)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

DELPHIDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Queso-Laptop)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_DELPHIDB = C:\app\Kristopher\product\11.2.0\client_2\log
```

And this is my tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Kristopher\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DELPHIDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = delphi.cs.csubak.edu)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = dbs01.cs.csubak)
    )
  )
```

Comment: What do you get when you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-12504%3A+TNS%3Alistener+was+not+given+the+SERVICE_NAME+in+CONNECT_DATA) that exact error message?

Comment: There are quite a few responses about editing the tnsnames.ora file, but I don't see that anywhere in the solution viewer.

Comment: `tnsnames.ora` file is a plain text file you can edit with any text editor (Notepad,  for instance). The Oracle documentation has details on its content. For the information you need to put in it, contact the person who told you to connect to the database; it's specific to that connection.

Comment: I have several instances of Oracle in the product folder. There is 11.1.0, 11.2.0, and 12.1.0. How do I know which one my VS is trying to access?

Comment: You configure it with the connection string. IOW, you tell it; it doesn't tell you. Did you not get information from the instructor about how to connect to the database? If you didn't, you should ask for it.

Comment: It looks like only one of them (11.2) has the tnsnames file. So using that one, and entering the service name of the DB as the ip address in VS, it says "Can not load Oracle client. Check your PATH environment variable and registry settings."

Comment: I did get instructions from him on how to connect. But once I started getting erros, he said he didn't know what to try. I have the IP and login info, and names of server and everything. Put that into the Net Manager that came with oracle like he said, but VS won't connect.

Comment: That means you don't have the Oracle client for the version of Oracle you're trying to connect with; download and install it from Oracle. Also see [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) for information about configuring your connection from VS.

Comment: How do I know which one to download? I assume you mean one of them from this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html and since I'm using the 11.2, I should do that release?

Comment: Please make an effort to think things through. If you're connecting to Oracle 11.2, wouldn't it make sense that you should download the client for that version of Oracle? And use the connection string for that version of Oracle?

Comment: There are 5 different downloads for 11.2 on that site. Does it matter which one I get? Will the newest one work?

Comment: You've posted a link to the 64-bit page. I have no idea what operating system you're using; I can't tell you whether you should download from that page or from the 32-bit page at the top. Once you figure that out, download the most recent version of the client that matches the version of Oracle that you're using. (If there are three versions of the client for 11.2, released in Jan 2013, June 2013, and November 2013, it would clearly make sense to download the November version - it's the most recent, and has bug fixes from the earlier ones (that's why they have new releases of the same client).

Comment: I downloaded the correct link from there and it still is showing the registry error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to keep trying and trying different options and one of them eventually worked. I have no idea how or why, but it did. Closing the question.